# Interrupt a C process called by an R function

Tags: r, external, interrupt

I would like to use an R method such as

```
    withTimeout(func,timeout=30)
```

to interrupt a potentially time consuming R library function which calls a C++ library function. This function does not check for R interrupts.

I have already figured out that this [cannot be done in RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43148981/r-not-responding-request-to-interrupt-stop-process).
Is there a way to do this in another IDE, or in native R?

Comment: R code can't interrupt C code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891073/time-out-an-r-command-via-something-like-try

Comment: Considering many (all?) IDEs call R in a fashion similar to RStudio, I am not confident that you'll get different results.

Comment: You just have to kill the entire process tree. So save your data before running the problematic calls, then kill everything and reload as necessary.

Comment: I'm aware of the option of killing the process tree. I hoped there was a more convenient way of terminating the c++ code which allowed R to continue afterwards. Since the above comments imply that this cannot be done inside R, I'll look for OS solutions.